# Material Design Bootstrap Select dropdown arrow issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please Find Attachment For Error

[image: Two Arrow In Select]

```
<select class="mdb-select">
   <option value="" disabled selected >Choose your option</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mdb-select').material_select();`enter code here`
         });
```

Comment: http://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/material-select/

You have to add css & jquery for material design bootstrap

Comment: Question is not clear, please provide your error and the code you have tried so far. Seems like a CSS error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I believed that the problem here is in your CSS.

Comment: Can you make demo same as given url for dropdown?

Comment: I think you have to add more to your question. I corrected my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27fey137/) and I am not experiencing an error